# Sum multiple columns in a row

Tags: excel, vba, sum

I need to be able to add the numbers up from one table column through to another table column

```
For i = 1 To PayRatesTable.ListRows.Count
 x = PayRatesTable.ListColumns("Weekday").DataBodyRange(i).Value: 
 PayRatesTable.ListColumns("BLANK").DataBodyRange(i).Value
 MsgBox x
Next i
```

[image]

What i am trying to do is add the numbers up that are betwen the red lines and assign them to x

Comment: *"Does not work"* is no error description. Please provide some example data or a screenshowt and explain what **exactly** you try to sum. If you get errors please tell which and where.

Comment: I guess `PayRatesTable.ListColumns("BLANK").DataBodyRange(i).Value = PayRatesTable.ListColumns("BLANK").DataBodyRange(i).Value + x`. But you should really specifcy what _"doesn't seem to work"_

Comment: Sorry, i have edited the question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Create a range of the columns and use `Application.Sum` no loop needed if you wnat the total of all the data in those columns:

```
x = Application.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(PayRatesTable.ListColumns("Weekday").DataBodyRange, PayRatesTable.ListColumns("BLANK").DataBodyRange))
```

If you want it row by row then keep the loop and use:

```
x = Application.Sum(Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(PayRatesTable.ListColumns("Weekday").DataBodyRange(i), PayRatesTable.ListColumns("BLANK").DataBodyRange(i)))
```